# Ошибка 2360 и 2361

Tags: c++, матрицы

Можете пожалуйста посмотреть что здесь не так . Заранее спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала здесь не так то, что в вопросе должен быть код в виде текста, а не рисунков... А в конце - после `case ...:` поставьте открывающую фигурную скобку, а перед `break` - закрывающую.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2361?view=vs-2019 вот тут же даже с примером есть